# import set_facts between playbooks dictionary/hash mapping

Tags: ansible, yaml

dictionary/hash mapping issue error for var post_token_headers.
doing this workflow in Ansible Tower is that would make any difference.

i authenticate just fine with my oauth.yaml playbook:

`- name: OAuth and Set Token Headers
hosts: localhost
gather_facts: false

tasks:
- name: Include OAuth Credentials
include_vars:
file: credentials.yaml

```
- name: Set OAuth Request Facts
  set_fact:
    oauth_request:
      grant_type: "password"
      username: "{{ oauth_creds.username }}"
      password: "{{ oauth_creds.password }}"
      client_id: "{{ oauth_creds.client_id }}"
      client_secret: "{{ oauth_creds.client_secret }}"

- name: Get OAuth Access Token
  uri:
    url: "<omitted>"
    method: POST
    headers:
      Content-Type: "application/json"
      Accept: "application/json"
    body: "{{ oauth_request | to_json }}"
    validate_certs: no
  register: token_response

- name: Set Token Variable
  set_fact:
    post_token_headers: 
      Accept: "application/json"
      Content-Type: "application/json"
      Authorization: "Bearer {{ token_response.json.access_token }}"

- name: Display the Dictionary
  debug: 
    var: post_token_headers
```

`

but when i tried to do the following in a different playbook (device_add.yaml):

`- name: Send SD-WAN Device Workflow
hosts: localhost
gather_facts: false

tasks:
- name: Include OAuth Credentials
include_vars:
file: oauth.yaml

```
- name: Create Device
  uri:
    url: "<omitted>"
    method: POST
    headers: "{{ post_token_headers | to_json }}"
    validate_certs: no
  register: device_response
```

`

i keep receiving the mapping issue even though in the debug (oauth.yaml) it shows:

`TASK [Display the Dictionary] ************************************************** ok: [localhost] => { "post_token_headers": { "Accept": "application/json", "Authorization": "Bearer <omitted>", "Content-Type": "application/json" } }`

the following tasks fails per debug (device_add.yaml):
`TASK [Include OAuth Credentials] *********************************************** fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"ansible_facts": {}, "ansible_included_var_files": [], "changed": false, "message": "/runner/project/oauth.yaml must be stored as a dictionary/hash"}`

I think i tried everything i could based on on other post and searches, "-", enclosing in {}
all playbooks are in the same directory, only a single host

Answer (score 0):

got it to work, unsure if its a workaround or the intended path but:
i simply added a tag to my playbook:

```
- name: Set Token Variable
  set_fact:
    post_token_headers: 
      Accept: "application/json"
      Content-Type: "application/json"
      Authorization: "Bearer {{ token_response.json.access_token }}"
    tags:
     - post_token_headers
```

i then imported the playbook and the tag

```
- import_playbook: oauth.yaml
  tags:
   - post_token_headers
```

and used accordingly